# Is it possible to add svg <symbol> into content property of pseudo-element like :before or :after

Tags: css, svg

I am using svg symbols on web page (http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/)

To add icon i should insert next code.

```
<svg class="svg-icon svg-icon_exit_door">
    <use xlink:href="#exit-door"/>
</svg>
```

Is there any way to use this construction in 'content' property of CSS selector?

Comment: Actually it is not a duplicate of the above question. This is about the use of SVG `<symbol>` "spriting" in pseudo elements, not just plain SVGs.

Comment: embedding / using svgs and symbol defs are different.  This question is not duplicate when considering using an svg symbol def file, and accessing the svg via `<use xlink:href="path/to/symbol-defs.svg#icon-id">`....